# SQL Same column subtraction

Tags: mysql, sql

How could I get this query to be in the correct syntax? (MySQL)

Thank you.

```
SELECT (count(a) WHERE a = 1)-(count(a) WHERE a = 0) FROM table
```

Comment: Actually in this case sum(a) could just work by itself I suppose.

Comment: I thought that too, but will it? If a=0 in 5 rows, and a=1 in 6 rows, `SUM(a)` will give you 6, and @Jonas's answer will give you 1. Which result are you looking for?

Comment: Rick, you are seeing SUMs instead of COUNTs.  Now, it is true that the above is equivalent to 2*sum(a) - count(*), assuming that a only takes on the values of 0 and 1.  Let's call that an interesting observation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN a=1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)- SUM(CASE WHEN a=0  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Result FROM table
```

Comment: I thought this was the answer but it is throwing me a Syntax Error. Does CASE work in mysql?

Comment: Absolutely. Read the reference here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

Comment: Sorry my mistake. There were two missing closing brackets. I've simplified it.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. So your query should work without the brackets?

Comment: ohhhhh I was dumb I get what you're saying now. It works perfectly now, thank you.